# beginning Computational Fluid Dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am starting a self study course in computational fluid dynamics.
I use ( An introduction to computational fluid dynamics : the finite volume method)
I am learning Python programming language.
The problem is that I cannot understand most things in the book

```
what do I need before beginning this course ?
```

---

### Update

My problem in the textbook (An introduction to computational fluid dynamics: the finite volume method):
I didn't understand the governing eqns. in ch.2 so I had to use another textbook(Fluid Mechanics Frank White)for refresh my information about fluid mechanics's eqns.

Comment: This question is a bit broad.  Could you perhaps specify a couple of the concepts you are having issues with in the book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the prerequisites for computational fluid mechanics is introductory courses to partial differential equations and numerical analysis. I haven't used "An introduction to computational fluid dynamics : the finite volume method", so I can't say anything about the textbook.

However, I would suggest checking out an online course by Lorena Barba:
         http://lorenabarba.com/blog/cfd-python-12-steps-to-navier-stokes/

She, also, has lectures posted on iTunesU. It is a useful resource.

Comment: First : Thanks for your advice.... second I will try this course but after a quick revision on Partial Differential Equations ... what is you advice for a textbook for PDE ?

Comment: I would suggest "Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction" by Strauss or "Applied Partial Differential Equations" by Haberman. I don't think you will find a simpler introduction to pdes than this. BTW, sorry for the late response. I don't check this account very often.

Answer (score 2):

I have attempted to document some resources for a newbie interested in automotive CFD here:

[http://www.vespalabs.org/Projects/Vespa_CFD%2F%2F3D_Model#Additional_Resources](http://www.vespalabs.org/Projects/Vespa_CFD//3D_Model#Additional_Resources)

I highly recommend the Hucho book as a starting point for describing the problem space from a practical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same thing last year after my first fluid course. I liked the weirdness of fluid mechanics so asked a graduate student I knew what book they were using in their CFD course, which he said was Versteeg. Being overly confident, I thought I could do it you know actually understand it. The problem was that I lacked a bit of rigor or rather I did not have enough knowledge in either physics or the math to actually enjoy CFD to its fullest.

So I did the 12 steps CFD with Lorena Barba while studying Mechanics of fluid by Irving Shames. I tried reading intro to fluid dynamics by Batchelor after hearing about all the praise, but yet again I was discouraged by my lack of mathematical knowledge. So I stuck it out with Shames instead of Batchelor.

Now after being acquainted with tensor notations and following all the derivations from the texts mentioned above I started to read and do the problems out of Computational Fluid dynamics:The basics with Application by Anderson. It is great, it goes over the physical meanings of the equation very rigorously and leaves very few to your guessing.

Another problem I had with Versteeg was the fact that it lacked problem set for practice anyway, now after completing all the coding exercises in Anderson's book, I have returned to Batchelor's book. This time I actually have some idea on what is being said in that book.

Also I am about to start studying numerical computation of internal and external flows by Hirsch. What I like is the rigor and plenty of problems for practice.

You can look up diff.eq , algebra or any other math ideas you may encounter online as you proceed forward with your study.

for learning how to use numpy and scipy and python in general I just followed this thank me later ;)

http://folk.ntnu.no/leifh/teaching/tkt4140/._main000.html#table_of_contents